# I want to get this output. How to cut out and remove a square from a container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, customclipper

[image: This is the output I want]

How to cut out a square from the overlayed semi-transparent container?

Using a CustomClipper just cuts out the square and removes the rest of the part. I want the opposite.

Main Widgets in the UI are;

1. Mobile Scanner
2. Semi-Transparent black Container

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/pskink/f63a595f50064a2f02bddc3d6e97fc85 for example